# How does the tensor product of matrices of dimension $2$ act on $\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$?

Tags: clifford-algebras

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$. I recently read in a book about Clifford algebras that its endomorphisms are given by $\mbox{End}(\mathbb{C}^{2^n})=M_2(\mathbb{C}) \bigotimes ...\bigotimes M_2(\mathbb{C})$ where the number of factors in the tensor product is $n$.
Can you tell me what this identification is? How does a tensor act on $\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$?

Comment: Hint: $M_2(\mathbb{C})=\text{End}(\mathbb{C}^2)$.

Comment: And $\Bbb{C}^{2^n}$ can be identified with $\Bbb{C}^2\otimes\Bbb{C}^2\otimes\cdots\otimes\Bbb{C}^2$ ($n$ tensor factors).